# On change regenerate a dropdown options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdown list that when i click an option i want another dropdown regenerate its options from mysql. The code of the first dropdown list:

```
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-zone"><?php echo $_['region'];?></label> 
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <select name="region_id" id="region_id" class="form-control">                    
            <?php
            include_once 'config.php';
            mysqli_query($conn,"set names 'utf8'");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM region";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if ((strpos($url,'/gr/') == true)) {
                    $perioxi = $row['region_greek'];
                } else {
                    $perioxi = $row['region_english'];
                }
                echo "<option value='" . $row['region_id'] ."'>" . $perioxi . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
            </select>
        </div> 
        <span class="error"><?php echo $option_value_error ?></span>
    </div>
```

It takes data from mysql and generates the dropdown list.
The second dropdown is under it and it is similar with the first instead i change the query and i want the query to be something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM region_prefecture WHERE region_id = '14'";
```

region_id is the column in the sql and the option value too.
So the question is that when i click at the first dropdown for example the value 3 i want the second dropdown update the data from mysql that the column region_id is 3.

I know that i have to use javascript onchange function but i don't know how to update it.

FYI: It is the same that opencart use when a new user register. Opencart use exactly the same for the country select and then it generates in another dropdown the cities.

Comment: Achieving this is a long but not complicated path, and there is of course many ways to do it. One very generic suggestion: create endpoints on your site that generate your dropdown data in JSON (using whatever way you fancy, multiple addresses, or one single address which gives the data according to the received _POST_ or _GET_ request) and then use AJAX to query your site for this data when a dropdown update event occurs client-side. You can (and should) reuse the database access code to generate an array of data from which you can easily generate HTML (initially) or JSON.

Comment: Since this answer is way too broad, it will probably be closed. But I'm sure that using your favorite search engine will give you many results and examples for the terms _"dropdown json ajax"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use jquery on change and ajax to achieve what you want.

```
<script>
 $(document).on("change","#region_id",function(){
  //$.ajax request, target.php is your php code that returns new option
  $.ajax({
   url: "target.php", //target.php should contain $_POST['id'], and a that would act as a return
   method: "POST",
   data: {
    id: $("#region_id").val() //get current value of region_id and send it to target.php
   },
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(data) {
    //if target.php is reached and returned data,
    //replace the option tags of prefecture_id select element
    $("#prefecture_id").html(data); //data is list of option tags returned by target.php
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: what code the target.php should have? the one that generates the second dropdown from the beginning?

Comment: target.php should have

**1)** php code to receive post values; $_POST['id'],
**2)** database query (if needed),
**3)** and a echo $result 

`the echo serves as the return statement, this will be stored to the data variable of ajax on success event`

Comment: As i test it i see that it creates a new dropdown with the data i want but it doesn't regenerate the dropbox i want. I 've tried to change    $("form").append("<select><option>"+data+"</option></select>"); to the form name but it doesn't do anything, i changed it to $("prefecture_id").append("<select><option>"+data+"</option></select>");

Comment: @AntonisPsaroulakis
Don't forget the # sign for the id.
`$("#prefecture_id")`.

In your code, is prefecture_id a <div> or <select> element? if it's a select element and you want to clear and put in new options, use

`$("#prefecture_id").html(data)` data should be a list of option tags returned by target.php

Comment: That is fantastic! It does exactly what i want! It is a select element by the way.

Comment: You're welcome man! Good luck in developing your program, thanks too! ;)